# How to parse JSON in C# and find only certain parts

Tags: c#, json

I have a file I got from a site that lists all textures and all names. I want to parse the JSON file and get just the name and texture parts get the url property and download the link with the name above.

I'm not sure how to get this because the whole file is large but I just want to get the url and the width and height. If they are 2048 or 4042. If they match get the name and download the URL and give the name value to the name of download.

So in summary

```
"name": "Metal_2_roughness.jpg",
"images": [
    {
        "height": 2048,
        "createdAt": "2017-08-11T16:14:06.933292",
        "updatedAt": "2017-08-11T16:14:06.933307",
        "uid": "ae19ea6db7074248ac4e04b4db971913",
        "width": 2048,
        "options": {},
        "url": "https://media.sketchfab.com/urls/cbfbf4d275c24eafa51eaf3a6c3c91b9/dist/textures/16fb95f74f4846079a32f15c2be35565/ae19ea6db7074248ac4e04b4db971913.jpeg",
        "size": 1042057
    },
```

If the height and width matches 2048 then check the name. Copy that then copy url and download the URL and give it the name property. But I'm not sure how to go about doing this as I never touched on JSON before.

https://paste.md-5.net/vecaxacafe.bash

Comment: use Json.net to parse it and then LINQ to filter?

Comment: `dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json).First.Children()["results"].First().ToList(); foreach (var result in data) { Console.WriteLine(result.name); Console.WriteLine(result.images[0].height); }` etc. You should consider to deserialize to a class model: much easier to handle. Btw, the JSON in your link is missing the opening and closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebRequest to request url for json and use Json.net to parse the response.

```
 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("your url");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            if (response.StatusDescription == "OK")
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.
                dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);

                Console.Write(stuff.results);
                //Iterate over images using a loop

                //Condition to check if height and width are same Eg: responseFromServer.images.height == responseFromServer.images.width

                // Store the url in a variable like String url = responseFromServer.images.url
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: should mention though the json i have is in a file not though url the file is here

Answer (score 0):

Use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to convert the contents of your file to classes.
Then read the contents with `File.ReadAllText()` and deserialize the content with Json.NET like this `var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);`

Then you can access the image height via `json.images[0].height`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting only a couple of fields from the entire JSON file, then the easiest way is to simply use JSON.NET and use the JObject method.

First install the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Package.

Then, you can do something as simple as :

```
var myJsonString = File.ReadAllText("myfile.json");
var myJObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
myJObject.SelectTokens("results[*].images[*].url").Values<string>();
```

Which will get you all URLs as strings. You may instead prefer to deserialize the entire JSON to an object using the JsonConvert method.

More Info : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/09/11/how-to-parse-json-in-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

To do what @MindingData, suggested in his answer, in Text.Json you can utilize the JsonDocument class like so:

```
var myJsonString = File.ReadAllText("myfile.json");
var myJDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(myJsonString);
myJDoc.GetProperty("images")[*].GetProperty("url").ToString();
```